# Probability of same last four digits between persons

Tags: probability

What are the odds that a person in one group of $105$ people, has the same last four digits of their cell phone number as another person in a different group of $105$ people?

I understand how to do this with only one group (the birthday paradox), but my intuition tells me that having two groups changes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't change things much.  Each pair of people has $1$ in $10^4$ chance of sharing the last four digits assuming the digits are randomly distributed.  How many pairs of people are there?  As it is a bit larger than $10^4$ it is reasonably likely (about $2/3$) that there will be a match.

Comment: So, if one pair has the odds of $.0001$, each person can form $105$ unique pairs, and there would be $105 * 105$ pairs total, how would I calculate the total probability?

Comment: The probability that no one matches is then $.9999^{(105^2)}\approx 0.33$  I was off in how much larger 105^2 is than 10,000.  It isn't much.

Comment: So, then the probability of there being a match would be $1 - .33 = .77$?

Comment: No, $1-0.33=0.67$ but then it is right.